# Logo of NVIDIA appearing during booting

Tags: boot, nvidia

While I was turning on my PC today (Ubuntu 14.04), and before the log in screen appeared, there was for just a moment a screen about NVIDIA which hadn't appeared before. It wasn't an error message or text but the logo of NVIDIA. The screen flashed so quick that I didn't get to see it properly though. Was there any updates that changed the way that NVIDIA advertises the drivers that the PC uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing weird about that if you are using NVIDIA's priopriatary driver... Perhaps it got updated and now shows that logo or maybe this time it just worked a little slower and showed itself for a while longer. I have NVIDIA drivers on two machines and one time logo shows and other is just too fast to notice or display does not react to screen mode change that fast...

Comment: You can also remove the logo with the command "sudo nvidia-xconfig --no-logo"